# Redirect domain.com to sub1.domain.com, do nothing for sub2.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect `domain.com` to `sub1.domain.com`, which I got to work with a .htaccess-redirect. But I have another subdomain, *sub2*. When I go to `sub2.domain.com` it redirects to `sub1.domain.com/sub2/`.

How can I redirect `domain.com` to `sub1.domain.com`, but do nothing when `sub2.domain.com` is requested?

*This is my .htaccess-file:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/sub1\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// This is not tested but you can try.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub1.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Welcome @JobOuddeken